# Trouble Embedding YouTube Video

Tags: html, css, youtube

Below my Navigation Bar I have a picture that is covered by a gradient, which fades into the div below it. After this div I have a footer.

I am having a problem trying to embed a YouTube video over my picture div and my gradient div that will extend slightly over my main div.

Essentially, the div that holds my YouTube video needs to go on top of these divs and be positioned in the center of the screen (from left to right), and be responsive.

However, I can't seem to be successful in doing this and all of the tutorials on responsive YouTube videos isn't working.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" />
        <title>Aduro Pictures</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="logo_home">
                <a href="index.html" title="Home"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="nav_link" id="about" href="about.html" title="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav_link" id="short_films" href="short_films.html" title="Short Films">Short Films</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav_link" id="cast_crew" href="cast_crew.html" title="Cast/Crew">Cast/Crew</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav_link" id="gallery" href="gallery.html" title="Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav_link" id="links" href="links.html" title="Links">Links</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav_link" id="contact_us" href="contact_us.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div id="main_wrapper">
            <div id="image_container"></div>
            <div id="gradient"></div>
            <div id="main_container"></div>
            <div id="video_container">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EuIXJIp8f6U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2016.</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    padding: 0px;
    }

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #000000;
    }

#logo_home {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 5%;
    width: 20%;
    top: 7.5px;
    }

#logo {
    height: 75px;
    width: 300px;
    }

nav {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 5%;
    width: 35%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 20px;
    }

ul {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 17.5px;
    }

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    }

.nav_link {
    font-family: 'PT-Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

.nav_link:link {
    color: #ffffff;
    }

.nav_link:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    }

.nav_link:hover {
    color: #dddddd;
    }

#main_wrapper {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 100%;
}

#image_container {
    position: relative; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 580px;
    background: url('../images/background5.jpg') no-repeat; 
}

#gradient {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 90px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 580px;
    background: transparent linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.65) 0px, #1D1D1D 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0%; 
}

#main_container {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    height: 1420px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;

    }

.copyright {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'PT-Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
```

Also, I've probably made some mistakes, or have positioned things incorrectly, in which case I apolgize ahead of time. I am new to HTML & CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not nesting the divs... instead, they are siblings. that could be the cause of the problem, unless you want them to be like that? try nesting divs and see what happens (div > div > div)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `position: absolute` to your `div#video_container`: https://jsfiddle.net/1aa87g9b/